# Letter 'p' disabled after last 16.04 update

Tags: keyboard, update-manager, 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
Desktop:        Gnome
Computer:       Samsung Ativ Book 8
```

I ran my latest daily updates this morning and now when I press the letter 'p' on my keyboard, it types nothing.

**Interesting Information:**

- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> works as expected
- if I turn on [caps lock] and press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, it types a lower case
  'p'
- I have a dual-boot setup and checked on Windows and my letter 'p'
  works as expected

Any ideas or even temporary fixes/hacks?

Comment: That is second question about similar strange problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763787/certain-keyboard-keys-not-working  Can it be some strange bug?

Comment: Could be. I'm typically on Gnome for my desktop, but switching back to Unity  gave me my 'p' back. Maybe the bug has to do with Gnome?

Comment: That's weird.  I must say, I've never heard it before.

Comment: Gnome has a lot of hard-coded key bindings, so it sounds like gnome is grabbing the keystroke, but why, by what exactly, and why not for everyone is a tough question. You might file a bug.

Comment: Start `xev` from a terminal.  Bring cursor to the `xev` little square window. Press `p` inside this window.  Any reaction in `xev`?

Comment: I did that and got
KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to get the letter p back by [updating Gnome to 3.20 using these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/how-to-install-gnome-320-in-ubuntu.html).

For reference, here is the [bug report I filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1579832). It was determined to be a duplicate of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1577125), where they recommended to just upgrade to 3.20.